# Get encoder name from SinkWriter or ICodecAPI or IMFTransform

Tags: c++, winapi, encoding, ms-media-foundation

I'm using the SinkWriter in order to encode video using media foundation.

After I initialize the SinkWriter, I would like to get the underlying encoder it uses, and print out its name, so I can see what encoder it uses. (In my case, the encoder is most probably the [H.264 Video Encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) included in MF).

I can get references to the encoder's ICodecAPI and IMFTransform interface (using `pSinkWriter->GetServiceForStream`), but I don't know how to get the encoder's friendly name using those interfaces.

Does anyone know how to get the encoder's friendly name from the sinkwriter? Or from its `ICodecAPI` or `IMFTransform` interface?

Comment: No one found a response to this yet? This seems a very basic thing to do, at least the GUID would help.

Answer (score 1):

This is by far an effective solution and i am not 100% sure it works, but what could be done is:

1) At start-up enumerate all the codecs that could be used (as i understand in this case H264 encoders) and subscribe to setting change event

```
MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO TransformationOutput = { MFMediaType_Video, MFVideoFormat_H264 };
DWORD nFlags = MFT_ENUM_FLAG_ALL;
UINT32 nCount = 0;
CLSID* pClsids;
MFTEnum( MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_ENCODER, nFlags, NULL, &TransformationOutput, NULL, &pClsids, &nCount);
// Ok here we assume nCount is 1 and we got the MS encoder
ICodecAPI *pMsEncoder;
hr = CoCreateInstance(pClsids[0], NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(ICodecAPI), (void**)&pMsEncoder);
// nCodecIds is supposed to be an array of identifiers to distinguish the sender
hr = pMsEncoder->RegisterForEvent(CODECAPI_AVEncVideoOutputFrameRate, (LONG_PTR)&nCodecIds[0]);
```

2) Not 100% sure if the frame rate setting is also set when the input media type for the stream is set, but anyhow you can try to set the same property on the `ICodecAPI` you retrieved from the `SinkWriter`. Then after getting the event you should be able to identify the codec by comparing `lParam1` to the value passed. But still this is very poor since it relies on the fact that all the encoders support the event notification and requires unneeded parameter changing if my hypothesis about the event being generated on stream construction is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Having `IMFTransform` you don't have a friendly name of the encoder.

One of the options you have is to check transform output type and compare to well known GUIDs to identify the encoder, in particular you are going to have a subtype of `MFVideoFormat_H264` with H264 Encoder MFT.

Another option is to reach `CLSID` of the encoder (`IMFTransform` does not get you it, but you might have it otherwise such as via `IMFActivate` or querying `MFT_TRANSFORM_CLSID_Attribute` attribute, or via `IPersist*` interfaces). Then you could look registry up for a friendly name or enumerate transforms and look your one in that list by comparing CLSID.

Comment: The MS H.264 Video Encoder does not implement `IPersist`, and does not support attributes (->GetAttributes() returns E_NOTIMPL). Also, the SinkWriter enumerates and creates the encoder, so I don't get access to the IMFActivate object. The only two interfaces that the encoder implements is `ICodecAPI` and `IMFTransform`, and it looks like I can't get a name out of either of them.

Comment: This is true. It is not designed to make this info accessible backwards from `IMFTransform`. It is hard to tell why, adding support for `IPersist` would be something easy and efficient. Whenever I would need to make a transform, I would definitely have it there, but stock filters are as they are... Not so much developer friendly.