# Getting codec name from IMFMediaType

Tags: ms-media-foundation

Is it possible to get a codec name from IMFMediaType? In my code I would like to log an audio or video codec corresponding to a particular stream index in IMFSourceReader. From IMFMediaType that I get from IMFSourceReader::GetCurrentMediaType() I get bitrate, frame size and all other parameters that the code uses to successfully play the media, but I cannot figure out how to get a codec name. I looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-foundation-attributes , but I do no see anything useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get encoder name from SinkWriter or ICodecAPI or IMFTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946419/get-encoder-name-from-sinkwriter-or-icodecapi-or-imftransform)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will check if querying for MFT_TRANSFORM_CLSID_Attribute works for the decoding case.

Comment: In my MFT_TRANSFORM_CLSID_Attribute is not set - I get MF_E_ATTRIBUTENOTFOUND when querying for it.

Comment: Try from other objects than media type.

Answer (score 1):

Media Foundation [Media Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-types) do not carry codec name information. The typical generic attributes that correspond to codec identification are [MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mf-mt-major-type-attribute) which is likely to be of no use because you already know video or audio media type you are holding. The second one is [MF_MT_SUBTYPE attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mf-mt-subtype-attribute) which essentially describes the encoding of the data in general. You are supposed to convert the GUID value to some user friendly "codec name" yourselves from there.

Comment: I tried MF_MT_SUBTYPE attribute, but it seems it gives the format of the output, not the original format that the media was decoded from. In particular, for h264 video I got MFVideoFormat_YV12, not MFVideoFormat_H264.

Comment: This is because both H.264 and YV12 are formats and hence "media types". Depending on the point in the pipeline you are querying this the format will be different. If you set source reader to not decode video you'd get media type corresponding to demultiplexer output (typically) and that would get you H.264.

Comment: You are right, I was querying the format after the the stream was initialized. Querying for MF_MT_SUBTYPE right after IMFSourceReader was constructed and its media type was retrieved using IMFSourceReader::GetNativeMediaType gave MFVideoFormat_H264.